# Create new application with Ionic 7 and Angular 15 but no module install

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I created a new application with ionic 7 and Angular 15 but when I call :

ionic start test blank -type=angular

The file `src\app\app-routing.module.ts` wasn't create and if i run `ionic g page page/myPage` no module was create.

Here all the dependancy install:

- @angular/cli@15.2.4
- @briebug/jest-schematic@5.0.0
- @ionic/cli@7.0.0
- @nestjs/cli@9.1.3
- cordova-res@0.15.4
- jest@29.3.1
- native-run@1.7.2

And my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "pokedexApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.7.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.7.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has updated to this feature called standalone which is set to true if you can go inside the .ts file,in your case if you have a app.component.ts,whatever the modules that were imported inside the @NgModules under imports array will be imported inside the import array of this @Component inside the import array,  i will provide the screenshot[this is how my app.componet.ts looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfqKV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will find the file app.routes.ts and for the imports: you can import in the metadata of the component for the standalone pages.

Answer (score 0):

Terribly uncomfortable. I need to use modular structure. I do not like porridge from the components.
I think this is a big minus of this framework. That they removed an important part of the Angular ecosystem.